# dynamic allocation and returning a local variable

Tags: c, variables, dynamic

In this piece of code I'm trying to create a list which contains all the chars form an input file, and my main problem is with the sentence "You can't return a local variable of the function" Iv'e been told which made me very confused. I dynamically allocated a List and return it, **can I just define `List list`** without a dynamic allocation and return it? I believe it's wring since all the information would be automatically deleted and I would be left only with the address of the original list I created.

Here's the code for more information:

```
typedef struct Item {
    char tav;
    struct Item* next;
} Item;

typedef struct List {
    Item* head;
} List;

List* create(char* path) {
    FILE* file;
    List* list;
    Item* trav;
    Item* curr;
    char c;

    file=fopen(path, "r");
    if (file==NULL) {
        printf("The file's not found");
        assert(0);
    }

    if (fscanf(file, "%c", &c)!=1) {
        printf("The file is empty");
        assert(0);
    }
    trav=(Item *)calloc(1, sizeof(Item));
    trav->tav=c;
    list=(List *)calloc(1, sizeof(List)); /* allocating dynamiclly the list so it won't be lost at the end of the function*/
    list->head=trav;

    while (fscanf(file, "%c", &c)==1) {
        curr=(Item*)calloc(1, sizeof(Item));
        curr->tav=c;
        trav->next=curr;
        trav=curr;
    }
    trav->next=NULL;

    fclose(file);

    return list;

}
```

Am I correct? Is this necessary? can I define List instead a pointer to one a return it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a pointer to variable local to the function. The local variable does not live beyond the scope(`{`,`}`) of the function.
Returning address of a variable local to a function will give you what is called as an **Undefined Behavior**.

You can very well return:

- a local variable by value or
- a pointer pointing to dynamically allocated memory

Prefer the first unless you are really bothered about the memory overhaed due to returning a copy.

> **can I just define List list without a dynamic allocation and return it?**

Yes,
Provided you have:

```
List create(char* path);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case returning the non-dynamically allocated List would be fine as well? I mean If my main function would use it as "List list=create(file)"?

Answer (score 1):

> You can't return a local variable of the function

This sentence is completely **wrong**. For example in this function:

```
int f(void)
{
    int x = 5;
    return x;
}
```

is a perfectly valid function in which you are returning a local variable.

What you should know is that you can't (or better say *shouldn't*) return the *address* of a local variable of the function. This is because after the function returns the address points to garbage and is not usable anymore.

In your example, you can very safely define a local `List` and return it.

Note that you still need to dynamically allocate `trav`, i.e. you can't take a local variable of type `Item` and the point `list->head` to it for the same reason above.

Comment: you are returning a copy to a local variable there.

Comment: @moooeeeep, I believe this is implied. Otherwise, what would "returning a local variable" mean?

Comment: I was told in this exercice that "The created list you must return by an argument of the function"-What does that mean? Do you think  that I was suppose to create "void create(&list, file)" function?

Comment: @Shahbaz Otherwise it's just a sloppy formulation not making clear how it really goes. The point is, the actual local variable is gone when the function exits but its _value_ can be passed as return value of the function. Plus, the address of the prior local can indeed be passed outside the function scope but you are no longer allowed to use it when the function ends (even though the old value might still be there, instead of _garbage_).